# iOS push notification .p12 certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am not able to create a .p12 certificate.. It is disabled for some reason..What am I doing wrong here? Thanks..

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to export `Certificate` then it'll give format as `.cer`. To get `.p12` file you need to export your `key` files. In your `Key Chain Access`, In `Category` section, select `Keys`.
[image]

Comment: Or You can export from the category "Certificates". Look for the APNS certificate you added..